# How to play youtube video using playlist in andriod studio

Tags: api, android-studio, youtube

my error is whan click on youtube play list and display all playlist videos. when click on video then app Stop working. So how to resolve this issue?

```
package com.app.dataapitest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistItem;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistItemListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Adapters.PlaylistAdapter;
import Adapters.VideolistAdapter;

import static Utils.Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY;

public class PlaylistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private VideolistAdapter listAdapter;
    public String nextPageToken = null;
    Animation slide_down,slide_up;
    int page = 0;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RelativeLayout loadingLayout;
    boolean isLoading = false;
    private ArrayList<Video> mPlaylistList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final GsonFactory mJsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
    private final HttpTransport mTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    private YouTube mYoutubeDataApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String id = intent.getStringExtra("Id");
        Log.d("Id:",id);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewID);
        loadingLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingRecyclerID);
        //Load animation
        slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);
        slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);

        mYoutubeDataApi = new YouTube.Builder(mTransport, mJsonFactory, null)
                .setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();

        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadingLayout.startAnimation(slide_up);

        new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYoutubeDataApi).execute(id);


        // Load more images onScroll end
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

//                 Check if end of page has been reached
                if( !isLoading && ((LinearLayoutManager)mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition() == listAdapter.getItemCount()-1 ){
                    isLoading = true;
                    Log.d(TAG , "End has reached, loading more images!");
                    loadingLayout.startAnimation(slide_up);
                    loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (nextPageToken!=null){
                        new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYoutubeDataApi).execute(id,nextPageToken);
                    }else {
                        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        loadingLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void generateRecyclerView(ArrayList<Video> result){

        // Set up RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(PlaylistActivity.this, 1);
        listAdapter = new VideolistAdapter(PlaylistActivity.this,result);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new VideolistAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(int position) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(PlaylistActivity.this,PlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",listAdapter.getItemList().get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("title", listAdapter.getItemList().get(position).getSnippet().getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("description", listAdapter.getItemList().get(position).getSnippet().getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("like", listAdapter.getItemList().get(position).getStatistics().getLikeCount().doubleValue());
                intent.putExtra("dislike", listAdapter.getItemList().get(position).getStatistics().getDislikeCount().doubleValue());
                intent.putExtra("views", listAdapter.getItemList().get(position).getStatistics().getViewCount().doubleValue());
                intent.putExtra("duration", listAdapter.getItemList().get(position).getContentDetails().getDuration());
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void OnItemLongClick(int position) {

            }
        });

    }



    public class GetPlaylistAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Pair<String, ArrayList<Video>>> {


        private static final String TAG = "GetPlaylistAsyncTask";
        private final Long YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS = 10L;

        //see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
        private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART = "snippet";
        private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS = "pageInfo,nextPageToken,items(id,snippet(resourceId/videoId))";
        //see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
        private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART = "snippet,contentDetails,statistics"; // video resource properties that the response will include.
        private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS = "items(id,snippet(title,description,thumbnails/high),contentDetails/duration,statistics)"; // selector specifying which fields to include in a partial response.

        private YouTube mYouTubeDataApi;

        public GetPlaylistAsyncTask(YouTube api) {
            mYouTubeDataApi = api;
        }


        @Override
        protected Pair<String, ArrayList<Video>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            final String playlistId = params[0];
            final String nextPageToken;

            if (params.length == 2) {
                nextPageToken = params[1];
            } else {
                nextPageToken = null;
            }

            PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemListResponse;
            try {
                playlistItemListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.playlistItems()
                        .list(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART)
                        .setPlaylistId(playlistId)
                        .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                        .setFields(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS)
                        .setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS)
                        .setKey(YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                        .execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            if (playlistItemListResponse == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get playlist");
                return null;
            }

            List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList();

            // pull out the video id's from the playlist page
            for (PlaylistItem item : playlistItemListResponse.getItems()) {
                videoIds.add(item.getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId());
            }

            // get details of the videos on this playlist page
            VideoListResponse videoListResponse = null;
            try {
                videoListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.videos()
                        .list(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART)
                        .setFields(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS)
                        .setKey(YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                        .setId(TextUtils.join(",", videoIds)).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return new Pair(playlistItemListResponse.getNextPageToken(), videoListResponse.getItems());
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Pair<String, ArrayList<Video>> stringArrayListPair) {
            super.onPostExecute(stringArrayListPair);



            if (stringArrayListPair == null) return;

            if (nextPageToken == null){

                if (page==0){
                    generateRecyclerView(stringArrayListPair.second);
                }

            }else {
                listAdapter.addVideos(stringArrayListPair.second);
            }
            nextPageToken = stringArrayListPair.first;

            page++;
            isLoading = false;
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            loadingLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);

        }

    }
}
```

Here is player activity

```
package com.app.dataapitest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoContentDetails;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoStatistics;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import Utils.Constants;

public class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

    public static final String TAG = PlaylistActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private YouTubePlayerView playerView;
    private TextView videoTitle,videoViews,publishTime,videoDescription,likeCount,dislikeCount;
    private static final DecimalFormat sFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
    private RelativeLayout videoLikes,videoDislikes,download,share;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        final String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        final String description = intent.getStringExtra("description");
        final Double like = intent.getDoubleExtra("like",0);
        final Double dislike = intent.getDoubleExtra("dislike",0);
        final Double views = intent.getDoubleExtra("views",0);
        final String duration = intent.getStringExtra("duration");


        playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.playerId);
        videoTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.videoNameId);
        videoViews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewsId);
        publishTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.publishId);
        videoDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descId);
        videoLikes = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.likeId);
        videoDislikes = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dislikeId);
        download = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.downloadId);
        share = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.shareId);
        likeCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.likeCountId);
        dislikeCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dislikeCountId);


        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        };

        // initialize video with details
        playerView.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, onInitializedListener);
        videoTitle.setText(title);
        videoDescription.setText(description);


//        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(duration));
//        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(dislike));
//        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(views));


//         set the video statistics
        publishTime.setText(parseDuration(duration));
        videoViews.setText(sFormatter.format(views) + " views");
        likeCount.setText(sFormatter.format(like));
        dislikeCount.setText(sFormatter.format(dislike));

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Watch \"" + title + "\" on YouTube");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });


        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "Feature not available yet...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }


    private String parseDuration(String in) {
        boolean hasSeconds = in.indexOf('S') > 0;
        boolean hasMinutes = in.indexOf('M') > 0;

        String s;
        if (hasSeconds) {
            s = in.substring(2, in.length() - 1);
        } else {
            s = in.substring(2, in.length());
        }

        String minutes = "0";
        String seconds = "00";

        if (hasMinutes && hasSeconds) {
            String[] split = s.split("M");
            minutes = split[0];
            seconds = split[1];
        } else if (hasMinutes) {
            minutes = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('M'));
        } else if (hasSeconds) {
            seconds = s;
        }

        // pad seconds with a 0 if less than 2 digits
        if (seconds.length() == 1) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        return minutes +" minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    }
}
```

Here is player xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".PlayerActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <view
            android:id="@+id/playerId"
            class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/descLayoutId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/playerId">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/videoNameId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Sample video name with chapter description"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/statusId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/videoNameId">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/viewsId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2,234 views"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/publishId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="15 hours ago"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/viewsId"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp" />



            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolsId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/statusId"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/likeLayoutId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/likeId"
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:padding="6dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/round_thumb_up"/>


                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/likeCountId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2K"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/likeId"/>


                </RelativeLayout>



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dislikeLayoutId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/likeLayoutId">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dislikeId"
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:padding="6dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/round_thumb_down"/>


                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dislikeCountId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2K"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/dislikeId"/>


                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/downloadLayoutId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dislikeLayoutId">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/downloadId"
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"

                        android:background="@drawable/circle">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:padding="6dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/round_download"/>


                    </RelativeLayout>



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/downloadTextId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Download"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/downloadId"/>



                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/shareLayoutId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/downloadLayoutId">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/shareId"
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"

                        android:background="@drawable/circle">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:padding="6dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/round_share"/>


                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shareTextId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Share"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/shareId"/>

                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolsId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/descHeaderId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Video Description"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/descId"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:autoLink="phone|web"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/descHeaderId"
                        android:text="Basic video description here"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please share your logcat  so we can see where the error occur